# PHP Composer: Debugging a Cache Miss for a Custom Repository's packages.json

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm using PHP composer with a custom repository.  For reasons that are beyond my ability to debug myself, composer is downloading the repository's `packages.json` **every time** I run a command.

```
$ composer.phar --profile -vvv --no-dev --repository-url=http://packages.firegento.com create-project magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer .
[4.2MB/0.05s] Downloading http://packages.firegento.com/packages.json
[70.6MB/152.18s] Writing /Users/alanstorm/.composer/cache/repo/http---packages.firegento.com/packages.json into cache
...

$ composer.phar --profile -vvv update
[3.7MB/0.01s] Reading ./composer.json
[4.2MB/0.02s] Executing command (CWD): git describe --exact-match --tags
[4.4MB/0.03s] Executing command (CWD): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
[4.5MB/0.05s] Executing command (CWD): hg branch
[4.5MB/0.12s] Executing command (CWD): svn info --xml
[6.6MB/0.17s] Loading composer repositories with package information
[6.8MB/0.19s] Downloading http://packages.firegento.com/packages.json
[73.2MB/125.50s] Writing /Users/alanstorm/.composer/cache/repo/http---packages.firegento.com/packages.json into cache
```

That's `152.18s` seconds for the first read, and `125.50s` seconds for the second.

This runs counter to the behavior of the standard packagist `packages.json`, which composer seems to download once and then read from cache.

How can I debug this cache miss further?  I don't know enough about composer to quickly track down where the "do i need to grab this from cache" logic lives, and I don't control the custom repository server.

Also, it's possible I'm completely wrong about the cache hit/miss theory, so any other ideas on this slow behavior are appreciated.

Comment: Did [your blog post](http://alanstorm.com/bypassing_a_slow_composer_repository) self answer this?

Comment: @biship Yup — composer's not meant to cache that file, so this question starts from an invalid premise.  In this particular instance we sped things up with gzip compression.

Answer (score 1):

Composer, by design, doesn't cache the main `packages.json` file, so my question about a cache miss was invalid.  If you're seeing a slow download of `packages.json`, your best bet is to

1. Enable gzip compression on the server serving this file.
2. Splitting up the `packages.json` file into multiple files.